# Max function sql in detail

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table where there are different financial years like FY18, FY19, FY20 in one column. There is another column where there are different Quarters like Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. Where Q1= Oct to Dec, Q2= Jan-Mar and Q3= Apr-Jun and Q4=Jul-Sep.

I need to make another column where I need to see the latest financial year and current quarter as a value of “True/False”. For example, If I want to see the data of 10 Apr 2020, I should select FY20 and Q3 and this will represent “true” in my result column. Can you please assist? I have written the following query. It is giving me the maximum for both FY and Quarter.

```
SELECT IF(FY = (SELECT MAX(FY) FROM `Table1`) AND  Quarter = (SELECT MAX(Quarter) FROM `Table1`), TRUE, FALSE) AS CurrentQuarter  
  FROM `Table1`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.FY_Quarter IS NOT NULL AS CurrentQuarter
FROM sourcetable AS t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(CONCAT(FY, `Quarter`)) AS FY_Quarter
            FROM sourcetable ) AS t2 ON CONCAT(t1.FY, t1.`Quarter`) = t2.FY_Quarter
```

> Can you please give me hints about the correlated query.

For example

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM sourcetable t2
                    WHERE CONCAT(t1.FY, t1.`Quarter`) < CONCAT(t2.FY, t2.`Quarter`) ) AS CurrentQuarter
FROM sourcetable AS t1
```

Comment: Thanks Akina. Can I use IF function or CASE instead of join.

Comment: @AbdurRahim No, IF/CASE can work with one current record only. You must use 2 copies of table. You may use correlated query instead of joining, but I doubt that this will be more fast.

Comment: Thanks Akina. Can you please give me hints about the correlated query. I would like to use  everything inside the same query.

Comment: @AbdurRahim Added.

Comment: It shows the error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Comment: @AbdurRahim *It shows the error* Who - it? The text provided is NOT MySQL error message.

Comment: I am using bigquery